# Regex to ignore match if content isn't numeric?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I wrote a regex to parse out a string in the form of:

```
Job Title (<numeric job number>) Location, State, Country
```

with this:

```
(?P<jobTitle>[a-zA-Z0-9,\:\/\s]+)[\s]+\((?P<jobCode>[0-9]+)\)[\s]+(?P<location>[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+)
```

But I ran into a problem when a job came in this form instead:

```
Job Title (extra information) (<numeric job number>) Location, State, Country
```

So my question is, how can I take in everything before the numeric job number as the 'jobTitle', the numeric portion as the 'jobCode', and everything after that as the 'location'?

For example

```
Super Cool Job (12345) Cool Place, California, United States
jobTitle => Super Cool Job
jobCode => 12345
location => Cool Place, California, United States

Another Cool Job (Not in california) (54321) Paris, France
jobTitle => Another Cool Job (Not in california)
jobCode => 54321
location => Paris, France
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be looking for something like:

```
(.*\S)\s+\((\d+)\)\s+(\S.*)
```

Comment: Huh, that was actually much simpler than mine. I added back in my group names: `(?P<jobTitle>.*\S)\s+\((?P<jobCode>\d+)\)\s+(?P<location>\S.*)`

Answer (score 1):

With this simple regex, your strings will be in Groups 1, 2 and 3

```
    $jobs='Super Cool Job (12345) Cool Place, California, United States
Another Cool Job (Not in california) (54321) Paris, France';

$regex = '/^(?m)(.*?)\s+\((\d+)\)\s+(.*)$/';

if(preg_match_all($regex,$jobs,$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Super Cool Job (12345) Cool Place, California, United States
            [1] => Super Cool Job
            [2] => 12345
            [3] => Cool Place, California, United States
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Another Cool Job (Not in california) (54321) Paris, France
            [1] => Another Cool Job (Not in california)
            [2] => 54321
            [3] => Paris, France
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all the fields, you can use this:

```
^(?<title>\D+) \((?<id>\d+)\)(?: (?<desc>[^,]+),)? (?<city>[^,]+), (?<country>[^,]+)$
```